# Converting PHP RegEX Sanitize String Function to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Attempting to sanitize strings in the same format across javascript and PHP.

This PHP function works perfectly as is:

```
function sanitize($s) {
    // This RegEx removes any group of non-alphanumeric or dash
    // character and replaces it/them with a dash
    return strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i', '_', $s));
}
```

Take the example string:

> `Test String - 20AS(AE)0121`

The PHP function brings back:

```
test_string_20as_ae_0121
```

Attempting to convert this to its javascript counterpart:

```
function sanitizejs(string) {
s = string.replace(/[^a-z0-9_]+/i, '_')
return s;
}
```

returns

```
Test_String - 20AS(AE)0121
```

What am I missing here?

https://jsfiddle.net/pwbqt8h9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution please check regex pattern :

```js
function sanitizejs(str){
    return str.trim().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "_").toLowerCase();
}

console.log(sanitizejs('Test String - 20AS(AE)0121 '))
```